# Track old and new values in two cells of a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need help tracking old and new values in two cells of a worksheet.

For example cell `A10` has an Y/N switch and cell `B10` has a formula output as value.

If `A10="Y"` and cell `B10` has changed, then I will trigger a macro named `Ballooning`.

If `A10="N"`, and `B10` has changed, then there will not be any action.

If I change `A10="Y"` again and even if there is no change in `B10`, the macro `Ballooning` has to trigger. However no other worksheet or workbook change should trigger the `Ballooning` macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code behind your sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Check if Cell B10 in current sheet changed and A10 is Y
    If Range(Target.Address) = Range("B10") And Range("A10").Value = "Y" Then
        Call Ballooning
    End If

    'Check if A10 changed to Y
    If Range(Target.Address) = Range("A10") And Range("A10").Value = "Y" Then
        Call Ballooning
    End If
End Sub
```

---

[image]